# HTML CSS Responsive Table & CSS Before

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

My aim is to create responsive tables design that look good when viewing on mobiles (width under 480px).

I have the following markup for my table:

```
<table class="table eventlist">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td data-title="Code">AAC</td>
            <td data-title="Company">AUSTRALIAN AGRICULTURAL COMPANY LIMITED.</td>
            <td data-title="Price" class="numeric">$1.38</td>
            <td data-title="Change" class="numeric">-0.01</td>
            <td data-title="Change %" class="numeric">-0.36%</td>
            <td data-title="Open" class="numeric">$1.39</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

And the following CSS:

```
/* Landscape phones and down */
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
        display:none;
    }
    tr {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:right;
    }
    td:before {
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    /*
    Label the data
    */
    td:before {
        content: attr(data-title);
    }
}
```

My table ends up looking like this:

[image]

Would you say this is a good user friendly responsive design?

How can I edit the line:

```
    td:before {
        content: attr(data-title);
    }
```

So that it reads the `<th>` for the column?

Here is a live example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liammccann1992/n4rUG/2/)

Comment: You can not select an attribute value of other elements with `content:attr(…)`, only for the element that the rule actually applies to.

Comment: So you couldnt do :attr(parent) or something?

Comment: Nope, you can’t. You can either redundantly put that info into another `data-` attribute on each of your TD elements, or you will have to use JavaScript to get the text from the TH.

Comment: Fair point, Will have a look into the most efficient, clean and least repetitive way of doing this!

Comment: http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/FCBEg?editors=110

Answer (score 1):

Re: Would you say this is a good user friendly responsive design?

The layout of it looks great for a single symbol, and still looks quite good for multiple rows when not in "mobile-mode", however if you plan on having multiple quotes, I think it's going to wind up looking quite cluttered on small screens. You might consider removing the borders between rows and only having lines between quotes to keep it visually cleaner.

Just my .02 from a design perspective.